# get userinfo gives 405 error on IdentityServer 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core

I have setup a Authentication Server using [Identity Server 4 sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/tree/release)  and I can access all other end points fine and also getting a bearer token .Everything works fine when I test using POSTMan. But when i use my code from html page,it gives 405 error.

Using Implicit flow. Also ,referred this [article](https://damienbod.com/2016/03/02/angular2-openid-connect-implicit-flow-with-identityserver4/) and code currently used

Answer (score 1):

My bad ,I was running into this [issue](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1372) which is discussed in github only.just updating the answer if it helps anyone.

added the CORS correctly and it fixed my issue.

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200"  /* et. al. */)
           .AllowAnyHeader() // allow 'Authentication' headers, et. al.
           .AllowAnyMethod() // allow GET, SET, OPTIONS, et. al.
           .AllowAutheticationHeader() // allow bearer authentication, et. al.
          // .....
    );
```